# Collecting User-Mode Dumps

Tags: c#, windows, registry, dump

I'm trying to collect Dumps from crashing applications using WER - by modifying Registry Key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting\LocalDumps
```

As stated here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787181(v=vs.85).aspx

However, the dumps - generated in the default folder location only : `%LOCALAPPDATA%\CrashDumps`

And not in a custom folder, such as `C:\Dump` for example.

I tried modifying registry manually (using regedit) and from code - same result
When I'm done this is the result:

[image]

This is my code:

```
const string USER_MODE_DUMPS_CONFIG_REGKEY = @"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting\LocalDumps";
const string DUMP_FOLDER_KEY = "DumpFolder";
......
Registry.SetValue(USER_MODE_DUMPS_CONFIG_REGKEY, valueName, "C:\Dumps", RegistryValueKind.String);
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: maybe 32 bit 64 bit difference?

Comment: I don't see where this could be, this is simply OS configuration...

Comment: You may need to reboot to kick the registry change in

Comment: Just, tried it - didn't helped, still generates in %LOCALAPPDATA%\CrashDumps. maybe it’s something with my OS version? Although it states – “Starting with Windows Server 2008 and Windows Vista with Service Pack 1 (SP1)”
 
Mine is : Windows 10 Pro Version 1607 (OS Build 14393.576)

Comment: may be `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting\LocalDumps` for wow64 ?

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out! for some reason my code wrote to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\Wi‌​ndows Error Reporting\LocalDumps and  not to  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting\LocalDumps I don't know why - but that's another thing. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @RdMm. I got the solution.

I ran my process as 32bit which accessed by default the :

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\Wi‌​ndows Error Reporting\LocalDumps
```

registry key.

Windows OS ignores that key, WER works only with 64 bit Registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting\LocalDumps
```

So, running as 64 bit process solved the issue! :)